# How to save and restore current state and values using PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to figure out a way to save the current state and all values in the gui such as the text in QLineEdit and QEditText widgets.

I found this [code](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/be8a476bb7038c7579c58609d7d0f031) which I have been trying to use and it seems that I can get it to save everything okay when I exit the GUI but when I open it, all it seems to restore is the window dimensions if I had moved them previously.

I can see in the ini file that everything gets saved including any text in the 2 widgets but I cant get the text to restore when I open the GUI. Does anyone know how I can get the text values to restore as well?
Here is what I am currently working with.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def restore(settings):
    finfo = QFileInfo(settings.fileName())
    if finfo.exists() and finfo.isFile():
        for w in qApp.allWidgets():
            mo = w.metaObject()
            if w.objectName() != "":
                for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                    name = mo.property(i).name()
                    val = settings.value("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))
                    w.setProperty(name, val)

def save(settings):
    for w in qApp.allWidgets():
        mo = w.metaObject()
        if w.objectName() != "":
            for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                name = mo.property(i).name()
                settings.setValue("{}/{}".format(w.objectName(), name), w.property(name))

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    settings = QSettings("gui.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        restore(self.settings)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.text_Box = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_Box.setObjectName("text_Box")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text_Box, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.quit_Button = QPushButton(self)
        self.quit_Button.setMaximumSize(30, 30)
        self.quit_Button.setObjectName("quit_Button")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.quit_Button, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.line_Edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_Edit.setObjectName("line_Edit")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_Edit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.quit_Button.clicked.connect(self.exitGUI)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        save(self.settings)
        QWidget.closeEvent(self, event)

    def exitGUI(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You're calling `restore` before creating the widgets...

Comment: Yeah you're right. I didn't know that would be an issue. Thanks for letting me know.